# Can´t force upgrade to Tomcat 7.0.42 from Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: 12.04, apt, tomcat7

I Want to use tomcat support to Websocket, but it has to be above tomcat version 7.0.26 which comes with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. 
I don´t want to run it stand-alone, want to try to solve it with apt-get.
In a 12.10 release the tomcat version is 7.0.30, but I don´t want to do a release upgrade to a non-LTS option, any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just download the Tomcat 7.0.42 binaries from its => [homepage](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi).

Extract it to a appropriate directory, e.g. `/opt/tomcat` and `chown` to proper user:group. Then you can start using it, start and stop scripts are in `$CATALINA_HOME/bin`. You don't have to use the Debian / Ubuntu package anyway.

NOTE: the configuration files will be under `$CATALINA_HOME/conf` instead of `/etc/tomcat7`. Also, if you want it to be started using sysvinit or upstart, you may need to change the init script a little bit and use `update-rc.d` or manually create symbolic links in `/etc/rcX.d` directory.